# D3 only one Y-axis on right for plotting line chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to plot a D3 line chart, with its Y-axis on the right, instead of being on the left. I used `var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y);`, but this code snippet plots my labels on the right, instead of shifting the axis to the right. The version I'm using of D3 is v4.9.1. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 9):

In D3, **no matter what** axis generator you use...

- axisBottom();
- axisTop();
- axisRight();
- axisLeft();

... the axes are **always** rendered at the origin, that is, `(0,0)`. It's the very first line in the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis):

> Regardless of orientation, axes are always rendered at the origin.

Therefore, you have to **translate** the axis.

Have a look at this demo. The first axis has no *translate*, the second one does:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().range([10, 140]);
var axis = d3.axisRight(scale);
var g1 = svg.append("g").call(axis);
var g2 = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(270,0)").call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```